# Measure word and vocabulary for internet posts

Tags: vocabulary, measure-word

If I want to say "There are 100 Facebook posts" or "There are 100 Tweets", how do I do so?

From Pleco, I got:
帖子 = post (forum), 
推特 = Twitter, 
脸书 = Facebook.

So is it something like: "这是百个脸书(推特)帖子。" or "有一百个推特帖子。"? Or does one use the measure word for books or letters or something else entirely. I was unable to find any specific information on this.

What would a native Chinese speaker say? What feels natural for use with counting internet posts. Of course, an example other than Facebook or Twitter is acceptable as well depending on what common social media web services are used in China.

Comment: For short posts, such as tweets and text messages, use 條. For longer posts, such as blog entries, use 篇.

Comment: And for tweets, you can also say 推文. For your example sentence, you can say 有一百条推文. However, for Facebook posts, I don't think people would say 脸文. Perhaps because 推 can mean "to promote", and "to advertise", it matches 文 more naturally, and it can really mean advertising texts/articles.

Comment: These make sense and help answer my questions. I appreciate your comments.

Comment: While I agree with the answers and comments in general, I have rarely heard people use 贴子 for FB posts because they are not internet posts in the historical (BBS) sense. I would use more accurate words - 状态(更新) for status updates, 文章 for wall posts (does this feature still exist?), 评论 for comments, etc. Also these words are fine for both formal and informal usages, while 贴子 is mostly colloquial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, you will say for " There are 100 xxx posts" as "有 100 个 yyy 帖子"

```
eg facebook posts = 脸书帖子
eg nytimes forum posts = nytimes 论坛帖子 etc
```

when the messages generally look long, you can use "篇" as well, when the messages generally look short, you can use "条" as well.

when there is a special term for eg "tweets", you can use "推特帖子" or "推文"